# Programmatically login to SAML SSO enabled site

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

My requirement is to automate a file download from an external site.
The manual flow as of now is to login to my intranet site and from there access the external site.

The external site will use my authentication from my intranet site. The external site appears to be using SAML SSO. My intranet site authenticates using Azure AD. How should I do this programmatically?

Comment: When you say that your external site "appears to be using SAML SSO", can you explain what you mean? If the site uses SAML for sign-in, does it also use Azure AD?

Comment: The URL gets redirected and i can see saml sso there. Final URL is of form https://site-name/view/index.cfm?page=samlsso

The Site relies on the login from my intranet site. I am sorry I can not publish actual site address, not sure about the company security policies.